# Angular 6: Why does HttpClient work even without importing HttpClientModule?

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular-httpclient, angular-module

I installed a barebones angular 6 project by running `ng new first-project` and I got a default app module and component. Now I created a new module and a component within it by running `ng generate module view` and `ng generate component view/view`. 
Now my app.module.ts looks like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TestService } from './test.service';
import { ViewModule } from './view/view.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ViewModule
    ],
    providers: [
        TestService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

view.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ViewComponent } from './view/view.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ViewComponent],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    exports: [
        ViewComponent
    ]
})
export class ViewModule { }
```

view.component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view',
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view.component.css']
})
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

    username: string = "";
    response: any;

    constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

    search () {
        this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/' + this.username)
        .subscribe((response) => {
            this.response = response;
            console.log(this.response);
        });
    }

}
```

So the thing is, I didn't import `HttpClientModule` inside view.module.ts but instead, did that inside app.module.ts and I directly imported `HttpClient` inside view.component.ts and I even got a response successfully. 
To test if this happens regularly, I removed the `FormsModule` import from view.module.ts to see if `[(ngModel)]` that I'm using inside view.component.html still works, as I already imported `FormsModule` inside app.module.ts, but it doesn't.

My question is why does HttpClientModule let me import it and use it inside different modules and why don't the other modules work that way?
I tried to find a reason online but couldn't find it. Can anyone please tell me the reason? Thanks.

Additional Info: 
1. `HttpClient` doesn't work if I don't import `HttpClientModule` anywhere.
So the module needs to be imported somewhere within the project.
2. It's working the other way also i.e. by importing the module inside view.module.ts and using it inside app.component.ts. This means, I can use `HttpClient` all over the project by importing the module just once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official document](https://angular.io/guide/http) of Angular, one is not required to import `HttpClientModule` in your `view.module.ts`, as long that you import it in your `AppModule.ts`.

Here is a quote from the site:

> *Before you can use the HttpClient, you need to import the Angular `HttpClientModule`. Most apps do so in the root AppModule.
>   Having imported `HttpClientModule` into the AppModule, you can inject the `HttpClient` into an application class as shown in the following `ConfigService` example.*

Comment: What brought me here is this comment from http.d.s: To use the same instance of `HttpInterceptors` for the entire app, import the `HttpClientModule` only in your `AppModule`, and add the interceptors to the root application injector. If you import `HttpClientModule` multiple times across different modules (for example, in lazy loading modules), each import creates a new copy of the `HttpClientModule`, which overwrites the interceptors provided in the root module.

Comment: What I am experiencing currently is, that without importing the HttpClientModule at all (not in the app module, not in any feature module) the injection of HttpClient in services works fine... no problems... is this valid? or something wrong if you do not import HttpClientModule and use HttpClient?